# Cool down games for gymnastics?

Tags: training, gymnastics

Does anyone know some good cool down games for gymnastics? It is for around 15 children and 2 floor strips. There are plenty of poxes, ropes and hoops that can be utilized.

Games which have been played but failed for various reasons are:

- What's the time Mr wolf (The children make too much noise when playing. When tagged the children are pushed)
- Green light red light (Children won't tell those who move to go back to the start)
- Duck duck goose (It takes too long for everyone to get a turn)
- Land and sea (The game has been played to many times)

Land and sea works but since it the only game that works it is played every lesson, thus over used. Another game which works but is bordering overuse is: have them in a circle and they jump (type of jump doesn't matter) and have to land (hold bike). The idea is to try and get all the way around the circle.

Comment: Welcome to Sports SE. Why have the games you have listed failed? "Various reasons" does not address that. I'm certain you are looking for games that the children will engage and have fun with while getting their proper cool down.

Comment: I have added why the games have failed. You are correct in saying "games that the children will engage and have fun with while getting their proper cool down: @edmastermind29

Comment: @edmastermind29 Do you have any game ideas?

Comment: None. Unrelated, and not sure you have this ability, but I have asked about [basketball drills for youth](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1150/basketball-drills-for-youth). Perhaps you can derive several games from that?